# How to extract the token value using regex?

Tags: regex, go

In this code, I am want to extract the token value. I did this to remove the extract the token value but it is giving me the following result.

**Result**

```
token-value"}
```

**Original**

```
{"token":"token-value"}
```

**What I want**

```
token-value
```

**Code**

```
re, err := regexp.Compile(`{"token":["}]`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    val = re.ReplaceAllString(val, "")
    return val
```

Comment: This looks like json, you should just parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternation for each end:

```
re, err := regexp.Compile(`.*:"|".*`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
val = re.ReplaceAllString(val, "")
return val
```

`.*:"` matches everything up to and including `:"`
`".*` matches everything from a quote (from remaining input) onwards
`|` means *or* in regex (technically called an *alternation*)